# Bloquear llamado de funcion en div padre desde un div hijo

Tags: javascript

Sucede que tengo un div padre el cual llama una función enviando en esta dos parametros (uno de éstos es 0 ya que será fijo) y dentro de este div tengo varios divs los cuales llaman la misma función pero con los dos parametros dinámicos:

```
<div onclick='abrirUbicacion(ID1,0);'>
  <div onclick='abrirUbicacion(ID1, ID2);'></div>
  <div onclick='abrirUbicacion(ID1, ID2);'></div>
</div>
```

Cuando doy clic en el cualquiera de los divs interno realiza el llamado de la función correctamente enviando ambos parametros bien pero inmediatamente ejecuta la función del div principal enviando el 0 como parámetro.
¿A qué se debe esto? y ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?.

Comment: Lo que ocurre se llama propagación de eventos, cualquier evento que ocurra en el hijo sera heredado por el padre, te mostrare en un ejemplo como evitar que esto ocurra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes usar el metodo `event.stopPropagation()` para evitar que el evento se propague de hijo a padre.

Ejemplo:

```js
function abrirUbicacion(ID1, ID2) {
 event.stopPropagation();
 alert("Ubicacion: "+ID1+", "+ID2);
}
```

```html
<div onclick='abrirUbicacion(0,0);'>Ubicaciones
  <div onclick='abrirUbicacion(1,1);'>Ubicacion 1</div>
  <div onclick='abrirUbicacion(2,2);'>Ubicacion 2</div>
</div>
```